# store infinity in postgres json via django

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql-9.3, infinity, django-postgresql

I have a list of tuples like below -

`[(float.inf, 1.0), (270, 0.9002), (0, 0.0)]`

I am looking for a simple serializer/deserializer that helps me store this tuple in a jsonb field in PostgreSQL.

I tried using `JSONEncoder().encode(a_math_function)` but didn't help.

I am facing the following error while attempting to store the above list in jsonb field -

```
django.db.utils.DataError: invalid input syntax for type json
LINE 1: ...", "a_math_function", "last_updated") VALUES (1, '[[Infinit...
DETAIL:  Token "Infinity" is invalid.
```

Note: the field a_math_function is of type JSONField()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
t=# select 'Infinity'::float;
  float8
----------
 Infinity
(1 row)
```

because 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-FLOAT

> In addition to ordinary numeric values, the floating-point types have
>   several special values:
>
> Infinity
>
> -Infinity
>
> NaN

yet, the json does not have such possible value (unless its string)
https://www.json.org/

> ```
> value
> string
> number
> object
> array
> true
> false
> null
> ```

thus:

```
t=# select '{"k":Infinity}'::json;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
LINE 1: select '{"k":Infinity}'::json;
               ^
DETAIL:  Token "Infinity" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: {"k":Infinity...
Time: 19.059 ms
```

so it's not the jango or postgres limitation - just `Infinity` is invalid token, yet `'Infinity'` is a valid string. so

```
t=# select '{"k":"Infinity"}'::json;
       json
------------------
 {"k":"Infinity"}
(1 row)
```

works... But `Infinity` here is "just a word". Of course you can save it as a string, not as numeric value and check every string if it's not equal `"Infinity"`, and if it is - launch your program logic to treat it as real Infinity... But in short - you can't do it, because json specification does not support it... same asyou can't store lets say red `#ff0000` as colour in json - only as string, to be caught and processed by your engine...

update:

postgres would cast float to text itself on `to_json`:

```
t=# select to_json(sub) from (select 'Infinity'::float) sub;
        to_json
-----------------------
 {"float8":"Infinity"}
(1 row)
```

**update**

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html

> When converting textual JSON input into jsonb, the primitive types
>   described by RFC 7159 are effectively mapped onto native PostgreSQL
>   types
>
> ...
>
> number   numeric NaN and **infinity values are disallowed**